# how to get the latitude and longitude when the page is deactive

Tags: javascript, jsp-tags

i am trying to get the latitude and longitude values in javascript using  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
            function foundLocation(position)    and forwarding it to the jsp page where the values are inserted.
it processes in a loop like manner , i.e ,again the first page is called and then forwards the value to jsp and so on,works fine when the page is active,but after the page is deactive the jsp inserts the last values when the page was active.

please help me to get and insert the values when the page is deactive

Comment: You need to provide some code here, so we could try to help

Comment: page was active / deactive sorry not able to get anything out of it, please add more information.